# What does ['x'] ['y'] at the end of python method call indicate? ['x'] ['y'] is mentioned at the end of function call

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

```
folders = make_request(server+"_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/"+path+"')/Folders")['d']['results']
```

I above question python statement, can someone please tell me what does `['d']['results']` indicate? What is it there in the python statement? What purpose it serves?

Answer (score 2):

It means the the `make_request` function returns a *dictionary* (which is similar to a hash-map in most languages, or a javascript object), whose 'd' value is another dictionary. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries about how dictionaries work.

Answer (score 2):

Just strict dict accessing.

It simply accesses the element whose key is 'd', then from this result, enters the elements whose key is 'results'.

```
request_answer = {'d' : {'result' : 'I am a result'}, 'other_key' : 'other value'}
print (request_answer['d']) #  {'result' : 'I am a result'}
print (request_answer['d']['result']) #  'I am a result'
```